# C# storing text in SQL Server for full text search

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode

Im writing an Outlook Add-in to file emails acdcording to certain parameters.

I am currently storing the `Outlook.MailItem.Body` property in a `varbinary(max)` field in SQL Server 2008R2. I have also enabled FTS on this column.

Currently I store the Body property of the email as a byte array in the database, and use `ASCIIEncoder.GetBytes()` function to convert this clear text. Currently I am experiencing some weird results, whereby I notice `?` characters occasionally for apostrophes and new lines.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the best method to store text in a database? As a byte array? And is the ASCIIEncoder the best method to acheive this?
2. I want to handle Unicode strings correctly, is there anything I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether FullTextSearch works best on VarBinary columns, though my instinct says "no", but I can answer the second half of your question.

The reason you're getting odd characters is that ASCIIEncoder.GetBytes() treats the text as ASCII, and can have exactly those sort of errors if the text you're encoding ISN'T ASCII-encoded. By default, strings in .NET are UTF8, so you're probably running into problems there. Use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` to get the bytes for a UTF8 string.

This also answers the second question - is this method useful for Unicode strings? Yes, since you're not storing strings at all. You're storing bytes, which your application happens to know are encoded Unicode strings. SQL won't do anything to them, because they're just bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info on varbinary, i was debating which way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to support Unicode characters and handle only text you should store your data in a column of type `nvarchar`. That would address both of your problems:

1.) Text is saved as variable-length Unicode character data in the database, you don't need a byte encoder/decoder to retrieve the data

2.) See 1.)

Comment: I have a feeling the original decision to use varbinary was support for HTML text, however I am no longer concerned for HTML and wish to just store the plain text representation. I may just give this a try

Comment: This solution will allow storage of HTML text, even if you don't need it.